# Display list of user along with count no of times the user login in log_history

Tags: php, json, pdo

I am able to list the user, but along that I want to show number of time user logged in for the day

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,username,date from user_tbl");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user_arr=array('data'=>$row);
echo json_encode($user_arr);
```

Based on user  id I want to count no of login from the log_history table, how can I use the below query in PDO json encode.

```
select count(id) as count1 from log_history where user_id=".$row['id']."
```

Comment: Can you please post output of `$row` variable.

Comment: id Username   date
1  vijay     2019-10-25
2  kumar     2019-10-25 
Expected output to be as below

id Username log_count  date
1  vijay     5          2019-10-25
2  kumar     10         2019-10-25

Comment: I think, It is incorrectly marked as duplicate. The duplicate answer do not run query in multiple table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, you want output like this:

```
------------------------------------------
id  |  username | date       | login count
------------------------------------------
1   |  user1    | 20-10-1019 | 20
------------------------------------------
2   |  user2    | 20-10-1019 | 25
------------------------------------------
```

#### You can do it with `Left Join`

```
SELECT user_tbl.id, user_tbl.username, user_tbl.date, COUNT(log_history.id) AS login_count
FROM `user_tbl`

LEFT JOIN log_history
ON user_tbl.id = log_history.user_id

GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: When you down vote, please leave a comment. So that I can update my answer.

Comment: Thankq Mahfuz, I got the expected result

Comment: I am glad, it works @VijayKumar